# cucumber debugger not stopping

Tags: ruby, debugging, cucumber

I'm trying to debug a simple BDD test using cucumber. In order to do that, I inserted a debugger statement where I would like to break the control flow. But it seems that cucumber ignores this statement.

I'm running the tests executing:

```
rake cucumber:wip
```

It's rather simple, so I think the code isn' t worth pasting here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `rails-debug` gem installed and/or included.

1. Make sure `rails-debug` listed in your Gemfile
2. If it's still not being included, make sure you run cucumber like:

> bundle exec cucumber ...